# If you pray out of it’s prescribed time without knowing it’s haram are your prayers valid?

Tags: salat, allah

I prayed out of it’s prescribed time without knowing it’s haram. Does that mean my prayers are invalid? I feel really ashamed of myself I feel like I should’ve known better.

Comment: Why should it be haram and why should your prayer be invalid? Explain!

Answer (score -2):

Quraan says about the prayers that, prayer is obligatory worship on muslims in a specefic time, if you know about the time for each prayer, and you pray it in different time, your prayer is invalid, but if you are unaware of that what exact times are, then your prayer is valid, but it will be most necessary for you to acquire knowledge about prayer times as soon as possible,
ALLAH KNOWS BETTER